# Get the height of a binary search tree - stack overflow error

Tags: javascript, search, tree, binary, binary-search-tree

```
BinarySearchTree.prototype.height = function () {
    if (this.right === null && this.left === null) return 1;
    var heightLeft = 0;
    var heightRight = 0;
    if (this.left != null)
        heightLeft = this.height(this.left);
    if (this.right != null)
        heightRight =this.height(this.right);
    if (heightLeft > heightRight) {
        return heightLeft + 1;
    } else {
        return heightRight + 1;
    }
};
```

I need to get the height of the BST. I understand the theory, but I want that the root counts as 1 and not as 0.

So if I had a BST like this:

```
             16             ---> lvl1
          /      \
        6         23        ---> lvl2
      /  \       /   \
     2    14    17    31    ---> lvl3
      \
       5                    ---> lvl4
```

...then the height is going to be 4.

My function runs into a stack overflow. How can I make it work?

Comment: What does your constructor `BinarySearchTree` look like?

Answer (score 0):

This is a good problem to use recursion. You will need to iterate through every branch of the three and save the max heigth in a variable. If you find a higher height, replace it in the variable:

```
BinarySearchTree.prototype.height = function () {

  let maxHeight = 1;

  const goThroughBranch = (branch, lvl = 1) => {

    if (branch.right !== null)
      goThroughBranch(branch.right, lvl+1);

    if (branch.left !== null)
      goThroughBranch(branch.left, lvl+1);

    if (lvl > maxHeight)
      maxHeight = lvl;
  };
  
  goThroughBranch(this);

  return maxHeight;
};
```

Comment: This coding style is less attractive than what the Asker was trying to do. Your answer is promoting a function with *side effects*, while the Asker has a *pure* recursive function in mind.

Answer (score 0):

There is just one issue in your code:

The `height` method takes no argument, yet your recursive calls pass an argument:

```
heightLeft = this.height(this.left);
```

Instead, you should call the method on `this.left` instead of `this`:

```
heightLeft = this.left.height();
```

A similar change is needed for the right side.

With those changes it will work, assuming that a `BinarySearchTree` instance has properties `left`, `right` which themselves are instances of `BinarySearchTree` (or `null`).

I would suggest using the more modern `class` syntax for defining `BinarySearchTree`, and shortening your code using the ternary operator, and `Math.max`.

Here is how I would write that class:

```js
class BinarySearchTree {
    constructor(value, left=null, right=null) {
        this.value = value;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }
    static from(firstValue, ...values) {
        if (!arguments.length) return;
        const root = new BinarySearchTree(firstValue);
        for (let value of values) root.insert(value);
        return root;
    }
    * [Symbol.iterator]() {
        if (this.left) yield * this.left;
        yield this.value;
        if (this.right) yield * this.right;
    }
    insert(value) {
        if (value < this.value) {
            if (this.left) {
                this.left.insert(value);
            } else {
                this.left = new BinarySearchTree(value);
            }
        } else if (this.right) {
            this.right.insert(value);
        } else {
            this.right = new BinarySearchTree(value);
        }
    }
    height() {
        return 1 + Math.max(this.left  ? this.left.height()  : 0, 
                            this.right ? this.right.height() : 0) 
    }
}

// Create the tree given as example in the question:
const tree = BinarySearchTree.from(16, 6, 23, 2, 14, 17, 31, 5);

console.log("inorder traversal is", ...tree);
console.log("height is", tree.height());
```